# running an Windows Store Apps from command line with arguments

Tags: windows, command-line, firefox, windows-store-app, windows-store

I have learned how I can run Windows Store apps from [command line](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675?auth=1) via:

```cmd
shell:AppsFolder!App

# For example:
  shell:Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

How can I pass command line arguments to such apps?

- For example, if Firefox is installed using the classic installer, I can start profile manager in a separate session via:

  ```cmd
  "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -ProfileManager
  ```

  How can I do the same when the app is installed from MS Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (passing the URL to Store-Firefox) worked for me from command line (replace the app id string with yours):

```
start shell:appsFolder\Mozilla.Firefox_n80bbvh6b1yt2!App https://www.mozilla.org
```

To do this from Explorer shell, run

```
"shell:appsFolder\Mozilla.Firefox_n80bbvh6b1yt2!App" https://www.mozilla.org
```

(note the quotes around the app name above)

Comment: Indeed, this suggestion worked. I have tried run in command line this command
    "start shell:appsFolder\Mozilla.Firefox_n80bbvh6b1yt2!App -no-remote -ProfileManager"
without quotes and it ran the command with no problems. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if "app execution alias" for the app has or can be defined in Windows: Go to Settings → Apps → Advanced app settings > App execution aliases, then check whether the app in question is listed, and that its status is set to "On".
2. If an app alias can be enabled, you can find it (as a 0-byte .exe file) in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps.
3. Aliases can be run straightforwardly with command-line arguments.

For example, to run Firefox with command-line arguments, you can create a shortcut to the alias %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\firefox.exe, and define any command-line arguments in the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know which specific app are you using, since not
all apps need to have command-line arguments.
This is especially true for Windows Store apps, which are in
principle designed to be run from the Start menu.

For some apps, you may find the app's `.exe` alias and use it in your
command-line.
Such aliases are stored in the folder
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.

For example, the Windows Terminal may be invoked by either one of
the following:

```
start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe"
"C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe"
```

Comment: I experienced the problem after installing Firefox from store. In my question it was cited as example, but at the same time, it was actually what I needed to solve in the first place. For now, I have uninstalled Microsoft Store version of Firefox and installed it using classic installer. Sometimes, I need to run Firefox profile manager, and sometimes different profiles as separate sessions. But if I found a way how to do it with Microsoft Store version, I could uninstall classic version and install Store version again.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but there seems to be no alias for Firefox in the above-mentioned folder (I installed Firefox from store to try it).

Comment: It works with some applications, but not all of them.