# How can I launch applications on Windows 11 from CMD that are located in the folder "\Program Files\WindowsApps\"?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-11

On **Windows 11**, I want to be able to run a script that launches sets of applications when I want to launch them. For example I want different sets launched for "work" "personal" etc. But I do NOT always want to launch these at STARTUP (are you listening Microsoft?).

Batch files work well for traditional exe files that are not located in the `\Program Files\WindowsApps\` directory, but I want to be able to launch application **Microsoft To Do** and **WhatsApp** from a batch file (or any other similar solution).

There appears to be a workaround in which permissions are modified to that folder and one can launch some but not all apps directly from their directory. This has many disadvantages such as when the path contains the version such as `\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Todos_2.86.53503.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`.

**Are there any simple solutions to this challenge?**

(One idea might be to launch a set of shortcuts with another shortcut or similar, but it appears that one cannot always create shortcuts to the Windows application in question here To Do, WhatsApp etc).

Comment: Please see if it is this that you want: https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/how-to-open-microsoft-store-apps-from-command-prompt/

Comment: See if [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1702711/8672) works for you.

Comment: These look promising. I will update once I have time to test.